# System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute

Tags: angularjs, node.js

> System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: URLs
>   requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL:
>   /Account/GetUser/

This error happens when calling http from Angular Universal. From the server, I have no access to the 'location' object.

Why is there a restriction in Angular preventing calling web services from a relative url?

How can I retrieve the host name without using 'location'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered it is injected.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const ORIGIN_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('ORIGIN_URL');
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by importing the following component...

`import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';`

I then construct my component e.g.

`constructor(http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL')originUrl: string) {...`

Then when I want to invoke my API I do this:

`http.get(originUrl + 'YOUR API URI HERE').subscribe(result => {...});`